# How to set a specific key in wayland?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, wayland

I already set `ctrl:nocaps` through `gnome-tweaks` to avoid pinky injury. However, I still need to have Cap Lock somewhere.

On X11 I usually do

```
printf "keycode  127 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock" > ~/.Xmodmap
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

to map Caps Lock to Break key.

Unfortunately, Xmodmap doesn't work on GNOME 43.1 due to Wayland.

How could I assign Caps Lock to Break key under Wayland?